# Word for "order doesn't matter"

Tags: single-word-requests

You have some data and some code that operates on it.  The *order* in which you process each data element doesn't matter, and hence the task is parallelizable.

The *order of computation on each element doesn't matter*, or the computation is ****_*__*_**** (not parallelizable!)

Comment: Do you mean that elements are computed like A+B+C+..., or that you compute A, then B, then C, separately? (Regardless of the order, just asking if they are all part of a single operation, of each one of them is an operation.)

Comment: Don't you mean parallelizable?

Comment: If you must have a single word, you could use *"sequence-independent"*. Or change the hyphen to a space and have done with it. I'm aware that this term is starting to have a different meaning in the world of genetic engineering - but I don't see there would be much chance of confusion, given OP's context.

Comment: btw - in OP's example, the missing word would be **"sequence-dependent"**, not *"sequence-independent"*!

Comment: "Doesn't matter order."

Comment: If we're talking about *processes* where it doesn't matter if they run concurrently (or consecutively in any random sequence), it may be that they are best described as [atomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

Comment: Originally when I opened this question, I was looking to rename an object I had called a `ParallelizableBatch`.  I always hated that name.  I recently renamed it to `WorkOrder`, which carries the implication that the tasks inside the `WorkOrder` may be parallelized, without sounding so rigid.

Comment: I wanted a word for this so much and I am disappointed that it doesn't really exist :( How unsatisfying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've got a lot of pseudo-synonyms here. For the heck of it, I'll try to relate them.

The term that describes the notion of unimportance of order is (unequivocally, in my mind) **sequence-independence**. A set of operations that are all **orthogonal** are (in other words) **independent** and therefore **sequence-independent**. A function over a sequence for which the order of the sequence is immaterial is **commutative**. If the function consists of a fold of another function of lower arity, then the latter must be **associative**. Sequence-independent operations are **parallelizable** and can therefore be run **asynchronously**. You can also say that the function has **unspecified evaluation order**, which implies *unreliable* evaluation order, which is something you really ought to document.

Answer (score 7):

You could say that the computations are **independent** of each other.

Answer (score 3):

I am throwing my weight against "**Orthogonal**". [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) defines "orthogonality", in the Computer Science context, as:

> Orthogonality guarantees that modifying the technical effect produced by a component of a system neither creates nor propagates side effects to other components of the system. The emergent behavior of a system consisting of components should be controlled strictly by formal definitions of its logic and not by side effects resulting from poor integration, i.e. non-orthogonal design of modules and interfaces. Orthogonality reduces testing and development time because it is easier to verify designs that neither cause side effects nor depend on them.
>
> For example, a car has orthogonal components and controls (e.g. accelerating the vehicle does not influence anything else but the components involved exclusively with the acceleration function). On the other hand, a non-orthogonal design might have its steering influence its braking (e.g. electronic stability control), or its speed tweak its suspension.[2] Consequently, this usage is seen to be derived from the use of orthogonal in mathematics: One may project a vector onto a subspace by projecting it onto each member of a set of basis vectors separately and adding the projections if and only if the basis vectors are mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for **Associative**?

From wikipedia:

> In mathematics, associativity is a property of some binary operations.
>   It means that, within an expression containing two or more occurrences
>   in a row of the same associative operator, the order in which the
>   operations are performed does not matter as long as the sequence of
>   the operands is not changed.

This usually only relates to mathematics. However I don't know of a word that is more general besides **Set**.

Answer (score 2):

What about *asynchronous*?

> In programming, asynchronous events are those occurring independently of the main program flow. Asynchronous actions are actions executed in a non-blocking scheme, allowing the main program flow to continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with [**Commutative**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Comment: I thought this one two, but this means something different than what he's asking.

Comment: @Aleanno Yeah, I also had second thoughts. Honestly, I voted up *asynchronous* and *independent*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the computations doesn't matter, you could simply say that they are *order‑insensitive*.

Answer (score 0):

"Can be reodered freely," or a shortening thereof.