# What's the word for the reversability of equal and opposite actions?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a desirable behaviour in user-interfaces (computer interfaces and machine interfaces) such that if you do the action and its opposite action once or more than once (assuming you don't reach an edge/limit) you should end up in the same state.

For example:

1. Pressing **right** moves the cursor right one character and pressing **left** moves the cursor left one character. If you press **right** five times then **left** five times the cursor will be in the same place, because **right** and **left** are `______`.
2. **Undo** and **Redo** are `______`. If you **Undo** 3 times then **Redo** 3 times you should be back to the same state.
3. Of a tool where the effect of one control depends on the current value of another control:

   The **length** and **radius** controls are NOT `______` when used together. **Length** is `______` while **radius** remains fixed and **radius** is `______` while **length** remains fixed, but adjusting either breaks the `______ity` of the other one.

Answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41265/word-for-order-doesnt-matter/41295) offer some good hints, but I don't think any of those are quite right. "Commutative" and "Associative" seem somehow appropriate, but are clearly specific to mathematics.

Comment: Newton's 3rd Law :P

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the word's "discrete" and "quantized" come to mind, only because these actions must be so for the behavior you describe to take place.

Comment: @SoylentGreen I thought you were right at first and was editing 'discreet' in, but I realised that in the length/radius example, length may be implemented by a wheel rolling along a curve controlled by radius. Turning the wheels would be a "continuous" action, not a "discreet" one.

Comment: Please note I changed "discreet" to "discrete".  Totally different meanings.  I was thinking of "discrete" when I first penned the comment.  I realized I misspelled it, so I made the edit.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for pointing this out. I made the same mistake (independently, not because of your mistake) and didn't notice.

Comment: how about counterparts?

Comment: left/right and do/undo are reciprocal pairs. In case #3, I haven't a clue what the relation between length and radius is. Do you mean arc length? The underlying idea that differentiates these cases is called [linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right and left are inverses or [complements](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complement) (in the limited sense that they are "either of two parts or things needed to complete the whole; counterpart."). They are also *counterparts*.

But this is a little different from what you're asking for in the title.

- *Associative* is a property when it doesn't matter what order you press them in (e.g., LLRR is the same as RLLR). This is borrowed from the math concept (e.g., 3+2 is the same as 2+3).
- *Invertible* is a property when it *has* a counterpart (e.g., Ctrl-Z is invertible with Ctrl-Y, but Ctrl-C is not invertible).
- (*Reversible* is another way to say invertible.)

You might also consider borrowing terms from set theory (such as L and R form an *identity*), but that might be too much baggage for a straightforward notion.

Comment: I went with actions and their counter-actions and discussed them as complementary to give context to the term and how I was using it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest "inverse" or "inverse functions"

> **adj.** Inverted in position, order, or relations; that proceeds in the opposite or reverse direction or order; that begins where something else ends, and ends where the other begins.

[Source: OED](http://0-www.oed.com.iii.slcl.org/view/Entry/99001?rskey=5rc2ut&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

For example, the inverse of left is right. Mathematically, the inverse of the derivative is the integral. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest **counteraction** and **adjustable**.

> **[counteraction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/counteraction)** *noun*
>   a force or influence that makes an opposing force ineffective or less effective
>
> **[adjustable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/adjustable)** *adjective*
>   capable of being readily changed

Here is how I would use them in your examples,

> 1. ... because right and left are ***counteractions***.
> 2. Undo and Redo are ***counteractions***.
> 3. The length and radius controls are NOT ***counteractions*** when used together. Length is ***adjustable*** while radius remains fixed and radius is ***adjustable*** while length remains fixed, but adjusting either breaks the ***adjustment*** of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The first two questions use antonyms. The third appears to describe a more complex relationship. If you have a formula for its relationship I can help you find better words.